# Load db data into javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using `Laravel 5.5` and I am trying to work with [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-getting-started) and want to load my data that is coming from my db directly into the Javascript file.

My Migration looks like the following:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

My Frontend looks like the following:

**example.js**

```
// specify the columns
var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: "Name", field: "name"},
    {headerName: "Created_At", field: "created_at"},
    {headerName: "Updated_At", field: "updated_at"}
];

// specify the data
var rowData = [
    {name: "TODO 1", created_at: "01.01.2018", updated_at: "05.11.2016"},
    {name: "TODO 1", created_at: "01.01.2018", updated_at: "05.11.2016"} // here I would like to replace this dummy data with my db data
];

// let the grid know which columns and what data to use
var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowData,
    onGridReady: function () {
        gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
    }
};

// used in our jasmine test
function selectAllRows() {
    gridOptions.api.selectAll();
}

// wait for the document to be loaded, otherwise ag-Grid will not find the div in the document.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // lookup the container we want the Grid to use
    var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');

    // create the grid passing in the div to use together with the columns & data we want to use
    new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
});
```

**home.blade.php**

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://www.ag-grid.com/dist/ag-grid/ag-grid.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Ag-Grid Example</h1>
    <div id="myGrid" style="height: 115px;width:500px" class="ag-fresh"></div>

    <!-- Own Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/example.js') }}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestions how to insert my data  that I load from the database into the the variable `rowData` in my `example.js` file?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting the data as a collection, you can just pass the data like this:

```
<script>
    var app = {{ $collection }};
</script>
```

If it's an array, you can use [`@json`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data) directive:

```
<script>
    var app = @json($array);
</script>
```

You also could use one of the available packages or put the data into a `hidden input` HTML element to be able to use this data in JS.